# Apache commons configuration spring intergration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-commons

I am new to apache commons configurations and would like to include it in my project. I have the following code from apache commons page

```
@Configuration
static class Config {

  @Bean
  public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(ConfigurableEnvironment env)
    throws ConfigurationException {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    MutablePropertySources sources = new MutablePropertySources();
    sources.addLast(new ConfigurationPropertySource("xml configuration", new Configurations().xml("aXmlConfigFile.xml")));
    configurer.setPropertySources(sources);
    configurer.setEnvironment(env);
    return configurer;
  }
}
```

Problem is if i do `envirnment.getProperty("some_key")` this is empty. Does it only work as @Value and not when using `Environment`.

Also how i can override properties at runtime and persists it to files they belong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableEnvironment env;

    @Autowired
    public void propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(ConfigurableEnvironment env) throws ConfigurationException {
        ConfigurationPropertySource configurationPropertySource = new ConfigurationPropertySource("xml configuration",
                new Configurations().xml("config.xml"));
        env.getPropertySources().addLast(configurationPropertySource);
    }
}
```

Here's my test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class Test1 {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("qa", env.getProperty("processing[@stage]"));
    }
}
```

Here's my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<configuration>
  <processing stage="qa">
    <paths>
      <path>/data/path1</path>
      <path>/data/otherpath</path>
      <path>/var/log</path>
    </paths>
  </processing>
</configuration>
```