# How can I specify an external configuration file for a java application that is not spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

### Background

I have built a console java application using kotlin and gradle.
The gradle file creates a fat jar which I can run from the command line using 
`java -jar <project>.jar`
The jar contains the application.properties file from which properties are read.

### Problem

I would like to specify on the command line that the application.properties file should be read from some external path.
When using spring boot, I have used

`java -jar -Dspring.config.location=somepath/application.properties  <project>.jar`

and this works.
But it does not seem to be working in the non-spring boot application

### Question

Is it possible to specify external configuration on the command line for non spring boot applications?

Comment: It depends on how the application works

Comment: Can you give me an example of how external configuration would work and indicate how the application should work in order for the external configuration to work?

Comment: it sould simply read a property for  a config location

Comment: And what should it do with that property? Manually load the file and read properties from it? That is cumbersome. I am using PropertySource and EnableConfigurationProperties and ConfigurationProperties so that Spring will read those properties for me. But because I am not using Spring Boot, it seems that it will not look for the application.properties outside the jar.

Comment: *That is cumbersome* Thats why spring intoduce the PropertySource. *I am using PropertySource and EnableConfigurationProperties and ConfigurationProperties* But you want a solution wirhout usinig spring?!

Comment: I am using spring but not spring boot ...

Comment: So you are looking for: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/SimpleCommandLinePropertySource.html ?

Comment: *I am using spring but not spring boot* It is important to know. a *non spring boot application* can also be a plain java appalication!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209226/discussion-between-david-sackstein-and-jens).

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot has a whole chapter in [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) which deals with various ways of configuration.

Obviously if you don't have spring boot you should implement something similar to it by yourself.

First thing you should decide - at which level you need the configuration to be integrated into your application:

- Do you only want to read the key/values from command line or maybe rely on environment variables or system properties?
- In general, what is the source of your configuration: Yaml? Properties file? maybe consul or etc.d?
- Do you want to create a java object that reflects the configurations that you've read (like classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` in spring boot do?
- Do you want to support only one source of configuration or you want the various sources of configurations to be supported?
- If you ware using Spring, do you want configuration properties to be automatically injected into beans?
- If you're planning to use properties/yaml (like `application.properties` in spring boot) - where do you want to place them? Non spring boot application won't read them "auto-magically", you'll have to implement this logic.
- Are you planning to deal with profiles (non-spring-boot application still supports flavors of loading different beans depending on specified profile).

Spring boot has answered all these questions and more.

Here are some options that you might want to give a try to if you're running outside the spring boot context but still have spring application:

1. Since spring 3.1, I guess, there is a`@PropertySource` annotation that you can use to make spring load properties from the file in the classpath or some "place" in the filesystem. [This article](https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring) summarizes the usage of this method as well as compares what spring boot has up on its sleeves as opposed to regular spring application. [This](https://mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/) is also a nice tutorial that covers regular spring features.
2. Something out of spring eco-system but still can be useful: [apache common configuration](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) project. There are some workarounds to integrate it with spring application, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48789587/apache-commons-configuration-spring-intergration)

Answer (score 0):

Considering all the answers here I concluded that though it is possible to enable external configuration in applications that are not spring boot, it does require some effort.
Therefore I decided to use Spring Boot in the container.